# Web-scraping through a list using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would need to get all the links of the following list of websites (from a dataframe column transformed to list):

```
urls = df['URLs'].tolist()
```

saving for each urls in a new column (`Links`) in a copy of the original dataset.

To get info from one of these websites, I am using :

```
http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('https://www.farmaciairisdiana.it/blog/') # for example

for link in BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print(link['href'])
```

This code works pretty well (I tested a few cases).

How can I iterate for each of those urls, saving the results into a new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate list `urls` and save each link to result list. Then you create new dataframe or add this list to new column.

For example:

```
http = httplib2.Http()

all_links = []
for url in urls:  # `urls` is your list from the question
    status, response = http.request(url)

    for link in BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            all_links.append(link['href'])


new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Links': all_links})
print(new_df)

# or    
#df['Links'] = all_links
```

---

EDIT: To create new dataframe, you can use this example:

```
http = httplib2.Http()

all_links = []
for url in urls:  # `urls` is your list from the question
    status, response = http.request(url)

    l = []
    all_links.append({'URLs': url, 'Links': l})

    for link in BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            l.append(link['href'])


new_df = pd.DataFrame(all_links)
print(new_df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrej Kesely. As soon as I can, I will mark your question. Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry Andrej, the new column should be in a new dataframe that is a copy of the original one, so I should have for each url in the dataframe a new column called Links. Is your code adding it? for example, for https://www.farmaciairisdiana.it/blog/ I should have a row in Links with the list of all the links scraped from it

Comment: I think the problem is that all_links collect all the links so I cannot add to a new column the links scraped for each link. For example, in new_df I should have one column with the urls and one column with links. For each url I should have the list of links scraped from it